# Argument of type 'Observable<Controller>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying to get user from database. Controller Service should return controller when passed username as a parameter.
Controller is just a specific kind of user.

The error I get when I try to parse retured user into Controller is

`Argument of type 'Observable<Controller>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`

Here is the part where the error occurs

**this.currentController = JSON.parse(controllerService.getController(token.getUsername()));**

Below is my code.

Controller Service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Controller } from '../models/controller.model';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError} from 'rxjs';
import { FilterSearchControllerDTO } from 
'../models.dto/filterSearchController.dto';

const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};


@Injectable()
export class ControllerService{

constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

private controllerUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/controller/';

public getControllers() {
    return this.http.get<Controller[]>(this.controllerUrl);
  }

public getController(username: string) {
  return this.http.get<Controller>(`${this.controllerUrl + 'getController'}/${username}`);
}

public deleteController(id: BigInteger){
  const url = `${this.controllerUrl + 'deleteController'}/${id}`;
  return this.http.get<boolean>(url);

}

public addController(controller: Controller){
  return this.http.post(this.controllerUrl + 'addController',controller)
  .pipe(
    catchError(e => throwError(e))
  );                 

}

public filterSearch(values: FilterSearchControllerDTO){
  return this.http.post<Controller[]>(this.controllerUrl + 'searchFilter',values);                 

}

}
```

ControllerView Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from '../header/header.component';
import { ControllerService } from '../services/controller.service';
import { Controller } from '../models/controller.model';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TokenStorageService } from '../auth/token-storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-controller-view',
  templateUrl: './controller-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./controller-view.component.css']
})
export class ControllerViewComponent implements OnInit {

  currentController: Controller;

  @ViewChild("header") header: HeaderComponent;
  showView: string = 'home';

  constructor(private controllerService: ControllerService, private router: Router, private token: TokenStorageService) { 
    this.currentController = JSON.parse(controllerService.getController(token.getUsername()));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.header.controllerView();
  }

  onNavigate(feature: string){
    this.showView = feature;
    if(feature == 'logout') {
      window.sessionStorage.clear();
      this.router.navigate(['mainPage']);
      window.alert("Successfully Logged out!");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You need to share the relevant part of the code for your problem to be understood. You might want to follow: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted it without my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service `getController()` method return an `Observable<Controller>`. So you can not basically return a `Controller` from it. Instead, you need to subscribe to it and get the value like:

**ControllerView Component**

```
constructor(private controllerService: ControllerService, private router: Router, private token: TokenStorageService) { 

    this.controllerService.getController(token.getUsername()).subscribe((response) => {
        this.currentController = response;
    })

}
```

Comment: Now it says  -- Argument of type 'Controller' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. It seems to me that is sees currentController as String, or am I mistaken.

Comment: No, it's my bad. `JSON.parse` expects the parameter to be `string` but `getController()` returns a `Controller` instance. Just need to remove `JSON.parse`. I edited the answer.

Comment: Glad to help :) have a nice day.